# Задать картинку в "return" в условии js или присвоить стиль с "content"

Tags: javascript, css, url, условия, return

Сейчас отрабатывает условие такое:

```
        function getArrow(num) {

        if(num > 0) return "↑";
        if(num === 0) return "-";
        else return "↓";
    }
```

Необходимо, чтобы вместо стрелочек подтягивались картинки, понимаю, что можно подтянуть стиль с картинкой, но как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы проста подтянуть картинок проста вставьте нужный тег вместо стрелочек.

В низу в моем случае я создаю теги **img** на лету даю им класс `blue` и загружаю с нужным `src`  атрибутом .

Если переменная `num` больше **0** то будет видно лампочка

Если переменная `num` равно нулью то пакетик

Если не то не другое то будет видно пулья

```js
let num = 4;

!function getArrow(num) {
        let img = document.createElement("img");
        img.classList.add("blue");
        let src = document.getElementById("x");
        src.appendChild(img);
        if(num > 0) return  img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/Simple_light_bulb_graphic.png"; //Если num больше нулья то вернет Лампочку
        if(num === 0) return  img.src = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/mycafe/images/b/b3/Simple_gift.png/revision/latest?cb=20170321134751&path-prefix=ru"; //Если num равен нулью то вернет Пакетик
        else return img.src = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/ark-survival-evolved/images/a/a0/Simple_Rifle_Ammo.png/revision/latest?cb=20151105094339&path-prefix=ru"; //В любых других ситуациях вернет пулью
}(num)
```

```css
#x > img {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.blue {
  border:3px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="x"></div>
```

Comment: Почему-то вернул мне ссылку на картинку, а не саму картинку, не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: @StanDan тогда проста поменяте местами img.src = "ссылка"; на src.appendChild(img);